# Accessing parameters of domain while serving html file

Tags: javascript, express

I want to access the parameters of the paths in my domain however im not sure how to send a static file while doing this.

this is what i want to do

```
app.use('/Game/:room', (req, res) => console.log(req.params.room), express.static('./Client/Game'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to return `express.static()`, so split the function into separate statements so you can log before returning.

```
app.use('/Game/:room', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.room);
    return express.static('./Client/Game');
});
```

Comment: the console.log does work but return express.static doesent do anything